# MySQL caps query at 21 days. why?

Tags: mysql, sum, where-clause

I have a daily date database, where my `Date` column is called `Datef` and is formatted as `YYYY-mm-dd`.

I am running a basic

```
SELECT SUM(Revenue)
FROM Databasename
WHERE  Datef BETWEEN (DATE_sub(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 day))
AND  (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 day))
```

This should give me the last 30 day sumation, however I've noticed that I actually gives me the last 21 days.

I know this because I have run

```
SELECT SUM(Revenue)
FROM Databasename
WHERE  Datef BETWEEN (DATE_sub(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 22 day))
AND  (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 day))
```

And changed the 22 to 21,23 etc. I also checked the data source and it is in fact stopping at 22 days.

In my case it is `June 30 2015`.

I've tried

```
SELECT SUM(Revenue)
FROM Databasename
WHERE  Datef BETWEEN (DATE_sub(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 23 day))
AND  (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 22 day))
```

To make sure my database is complete and I get the correct output.

I'm wondering if I have to set up my dates differently or if there is a cap on interval day sumations?

Comment: There is no cap.  Can you post a set of sample rows illustrating the problem? You may directly perform the interval subtraction, without `DATE_SUB()`. It won't change the result, but makes for a cleaner query:  `BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)`

Comment: Do a test: hardcode in the BETWEEN values - '2015-06-21' and '2015-07-20'. Good luck.